# How to make projection to display limited data

Tags: mongodb

How to display only limited data into response rather than whole object

```
  {
        "message": "Records",
        "data": [
            {
                "_id": "5f3ccf2448e5181dc80a70d3",
                "string": "string",
                "records": [
                    {
                        "_id": "5f3ccfc35417491564bbe2z9",
                        "product_id": "5ecd3a93f1314915404xd6ds",
                        "my_detail": {
                            "_id": "5ecc00f97c96f408384d57c4",
                            "active": 0,
                            "status": "pending",
                            "deleted_at": 0,
                            "email": "records@yopmail.com",
                            "password": "$2a$12$7h3mttR8TUlZZKIzQvnVV.1sdfsd56.sdfsdfBOxA6UBkpRBLFVC",
                            "first_name": "Johny",
                            "last_name": "Hales",
                            "createdAt": "2020-05-25T17:31:37.016Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2020-05-25T17:31:37.016Z",
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "_id": "5f3ccfc35417491564bbe2z9",
                        "product_id": "5ecd3a93f1314915404xd6ds",
                        "my_detail": {
                            "_id": "5ecc00f97c96f408384d57c4",
                            "active": 0,
                            "status": "pending",
                            "deleted_at": 0,
                            "email": "records@yopmail.com",
                            "password": "$2a$12$7h3mttR8TUlZZKIzQvnVV.1sdfsd56.sdfsdfBOxA6UBkpRBLFVC",
                            "first_name": "Steve",
                            "last_name": "harvey",
                            "createdAt": "2020-05-25T17:31:37.016Z",
                            "updatedAt": "2020-05-25T17:31:37.016Z",
                        }
                    },
                ]
            }
        ],
    }
```

my_detail should display only first_name, last_name and status from my_detail object not to display everything like _id, active email, password an all, tried difference way does not get success please guide.

How to make projection to display limited data

```
$project : {
    "string":1,
    "records":1,
    "records.my_detail.first_name":1,
    "records.my_detail.last_name" :1,
    "records.my_detail.status" :1

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done was correct, but you have one upper level array `data[]`. So you need to include it also

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "data.records.my_detail.first_name": 1,
      "data.records.my_detail.last_name": 1,
      "data.records.my_detail.status": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mzNCSZwNyAF)

Comment: So  can;t you use `mydetails` in query?

Comment: lol, i didnt notice that you commented, i thought owner of the post commented.

Comment: what he wants to do is, he just need to modify the query if I'm wrong

Comment: yes, I got it. we will take a look on his comment and will try to give a solution based on his req

Comment: You are awesome, you are giving a quick response to each questions, much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for responding back, turvishal is correct, records are coming after $lookup and I want not display everything only to display first_name, last_name and status only

Comment: Have you tried that @turivishal provide you the solution "records.my_detail.first_name":1

Comment: Certainly there is a problem with your code please provide the same.

Comment: Ohh dear just remove or comment this => "records":1

Comment: @turivishal are `data` and `message` provided by mongoose?

Comment: @turivishal huff, I was so confused about it. I'm not a mongose guy :'(.

Comment: I am clearing my comments, i think issue is resolved and comments are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this if not going for aggregation:

```
db.collection.find({},
{
_id: 0,
"data.records.my_detail.first_name": 1,
"data.records.my_detail.last_name": 1,
"data.records.my_detail.status": 1
})
```